# WPF Dynamically Generated DataGrid (Devexpress dxg:GridControl)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid, devexpress-wpf

I have one requirement in which I have to display some readonly data with editable checkbox controls on grid (on devexpress gridcontrol)  for user input but these columns should be dynamically generated.Any changes done grid (checkboxes) are to be saved in back-end.

For this I referred this article:

Dynamic datagrid http://paulstovell.com/blog/dynamic-datagrid

The code is working fine if I am using with Visual Studio (2010) WPF Datagrid.But when I use devexpress gridcontrol instead of gridcontrol(checbox columns) are not editable by default.To resolve this I used datatemplate but I am facing another issue these are not updating in code behind collection despite being mode "TwoWay".

Any help would be appreciated.

Environment : VS 2010 , WPF , Devexpress control 12.1

Code snippet changes for devexpress gridcontrol are below:

(INotifyPropertyChanged implemented)

```
private ObservableCollection<Record> records;

public ObservableCollection<Record> Records
        {
            get
            {
                return records;
            }
            set
            {
                records = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(() => Records);
            }

        }
```

Constructor part :

```
records = new ObservableCollection<Record>();

Records.Add(new Record(new Property("FirstName", "Paul"), new Property("LastName", "Stovell"), new Property("IsEnabled", true)));
Records.Add(new Record(new Property("FirstName", "Tony"), new Property("LastName", "Black"), new Property("IsEnabled", false)));

   var columns = Records.First()
    .Properties
    .Select((x, i) => new { Name = x.Name, Index = i })
    .ToArray();

            foreach (var column in columns)
            {
                var x = string.Format("Properties[{0}].Value", column.Index);
                var binding = new Binding(string.Format("Properties[{0}].Value", column.Index));


                {
                    dataGrid.Columns.Add(new GridColumn()
                        {
                            Header = column.Name,

                            DisplayMemberBinding = binding,
                            AllowEditing = DefaultBoolean.True,
                           CellTemplate = (DataTemplate)Application.Current.FindResource("AttributeDisplayTemplate")
                        });
                }



<DataTemplate x:Key="AttributeDisplayTemplate">
        <CheckBox MinWidth="70"  IsEnabled="True" IsChecked="{Binding Path=Value,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"   />
    </DataTemplate>
```

Xaml Part

```
  <dxg:GridControl x:Name="dataGrid"  ItemsSource="{Binding Records}" 
 AutoPopulateColumns="False" IsEnabled="True"    Width="650">

            <dxg:GridControl.View>
                <dxg:TableView BestFitArea="All" AllowBestFit="True" ShowGroupPanel="False" NavigationStyle="Cell"  
                                    >
                </dxg:TableView>
            </dxg:GridControl.View>
        </dxg:GridControl>
```

Comment: It is strongly recommended that you **define** the UI in XAML as opposed to procedurally creating it in code. Use DataTemplates to switch views as needed depending on the data shown and use strongly typed data models as opposed to "magic string" based stuff. WPF's idea of "dynamic" is very different from other technologies, and this "one size fits all" solution is not adequate in most cases due to the complexity of the Visual Tree and the lack of ability to properly customize the UI when needed. WPF is not winforms.

Comment: I agree with you.At design time I don't have information about dynamic columns to be displayed (especially the checkbox columns).I required to take user input on grid UI.The same thing working fine with WPF datagrid but not with devexpress grid control.The property AllowEditing in GridColumn have no effect.